# Undefined symbol when clang compiling to target wasm

Tags: c++, linker, clang, webassembly

So I have managed to get some simple webassembly application running in the browser, I managed to call webassembly code from Javascript. However when I try to call Javascript from C code I can't get the code to compile

I am using clang 9.0 and wasi-libc. How I am compiling:

clang --target=wasm32-wasi -Wl,--allow-undefined-file=src/wasm.syms -Wl,--export-all --sysroot wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot -O2 -s -o ./public/main.wasm ./src/main.cpp

src/main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void __console_log(int str, int len);

int main()
{
    printf("MAIN!\n");
    return 0;
}

extern "C"
{
    void test()
    {
        char *str = "TEST!";
        __console_log((int)str, 5);
    }

    int test2()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

wasm.syms:

```
__console_log
```

If I remove the references to `__console_log` in the cpp file it works, but when I add it I keep getting a linking error even though I have `--allow-undefined-file=src/wasm.syms` in the command line (tried with -U=__console_log as well, same error):

`wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/vl/4bjdkcfx1gncfx0vzrl0s57c0000gn/T/main-a723f9.o: undefined symbol: __console_log(int, int)`

Here is the full logs when running with the `-v` flag:

```
$ clang --target=wasm32-wasi -Wl,--allow-undefined-file=src/wasm.syms -Wl,--export-all --sysroot /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot -O2 -s -o ./public/main.wasm ./src/main.cpp -v
clang version 9.0.0 (git://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 0399d5a9682b3cef71c653373e38890c63c4c365)
Target: wasm32-unknown-wasi
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/bin
 "/Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/bin/clang-9" -cc1 -triple wasm32-unknown-wasi -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu generic -fvisibility hidden -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -target-linker-version 512.4 -momit-leaf-frame-pointer -v -resource-dir /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/lib/clang/9.0.0 -isysroot /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot -internal-isystem /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include/wasm32-wasi/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/lib/clang/9.0.0/include -internal-isystem /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include/wasm32-wasi -internal-isystem /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include -O2 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 102 -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o /var/folders/vl/4bjdkcfx1gncfx0vzrl0s57c0000gn/T/main-a723f9.o -x c++ ./src/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 based upon LLVM 9.0.0 default target x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include/wasm32-wasi/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include/c++/v1"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include/wasm32-wasi"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/lib/clang/9.0.0/include
 /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/include
End of search list.
./src/main.cpp:17:21: warning: ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *'
      [-Wwritable-strings]
        char *str = "TEST!";
                    ^
1 warning generated.
 "/Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/bin/wasm-ld" --strip-all -L/Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/lib/wasm32-wasi /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/wasi-libc/sysroot/lib/wasm32-wasi/crt1.o --allow-undefined-file=src/wasm.syms --export-all /var/folders/vl/4bjdkcfx1gncfx0vzrl0s57c0000gn/T/main-a723f9.o -lc /Users/hoff/dev/wasm-test/clang/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/wasi/libclang_rt.builtins-wasm32.a -o ./public/main.wasm
wasm-ld: error: /var/folders/vl/4bjdkcfx1gncfx0vzrl0s57c0000gn/T/main-a723f9.o: undefined symbol: __console_log(int, int)
clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also declare `__console_log` as extern "C".  That clue is in that fact that function signature is included in the error message.   lld is demanding the C++ symbol here (perhaps it would be more clear if it didn't, I'm not sure).

Comment: oh my god that was exactly it, makes sense as the names outside extern "C" get mangled :facepalm:.
If you are familiar with wasm, do you know if wasi-libc replaces the need to send imports in the second parameter of WebAssembly.instantiate? My impression was that wasi-libc was meant to implement as much as possible from libc api without the need OS calls. For clarification I am trying to run wasm code in the browser and I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of wasmer/similar runtimes

Comment: You will alwasy need to set of imports to do anything useful.  Wasi libc is built on a set of syscall that need to be implemented by the host.  You can't implement such things in pure wasm since it has not capabilities other than compute.

Comment: yeah I imagined that would be the case, afterall you need some basic functionality to come from outside of the wasm like the memory allocator and IO. I just find it weird how big wasmer is, it makes a huge dent on bundlesize,makes it prohibitive to use wasm in non-lazy-loaded scenarios.
I have seen a few github repos with their own small runtimes, but it is a lot of work and requires a lot of knowledge to build something that will fit my needs exactly
Funny fact, I was testing out clang/wasi compiling to wasm, using std::cout increases the .wasm file size by over 900kb...

Comment: stdio.h printf adds only about 10kb. Funny how wasm is the worse of both worlds for developers, need to care about bundle size as well as crazy compiler/linker toolchain